# Using of phrases - to catch up with

Tags: phrasal-verbs

If I have got too many things to do and very little time for it.

Can I say " I can not catch up with all of these".

Comment: Hello, Sanjar Igamov. Have you consulted a dictionary to see whether "catch up" is defined in a way relevant to the sense you have in mind? If so, what did the dictionary say?

Comment: Hello, yes I have, it's similar but no exactly what I meant.

Comment: However, it is more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

The expression here should be *to catch up **on** (chores/reading/accounts)*.

"I cannot (or can not) catch up on all of these."

Examples for *"to catch up **with**"*:

1. Succeed in reaching a person who is ahead of one:
   "You go with Stasia and Katie, and I’ll catch up with you."
2. Talk to (someone) whom one has not seen for some time in order to find out
   what he or she has been doing in the interim:
   "Had a chance to catch up with old friends."
3. Begin to have a damaging effect on:
   "The physical exertions began to catch up with Sue."

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/catch+up+on